# How to send server metrics data to statsd?

Tags: monitoring, statsd, grafana

Our monitoring stack is Grafana + InluxDB + statsD.

We use it for application monitoring.

We need to add server metrics (CPU, memory, network connections, etc...) to Grafana, so I'm guessing we'll need some agent to collect server metrics and pass to statsD.

Do you know of any agent that can do that? or any other way to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collectd` deamon for system metrics. Use the provided plugins to collect the information you need. To feed into Influx use the network plugin and configure your InfluxDB Server Params.

On the InfluxDB side you will need to create a database for `collectd`.

```
[collectd]
enabled = true
port = YOURPORT where COLLECTD is sending the data.
database = "collectd_db"
typesdb = "/opt/collectd/share/collectd/types.db"
```

restart Influxdb with that `config.toml`.

Step by STEP can be found here https://anomaly.io/collectd-metrics-to-influxdb/

Answer (score 1):

I've decided to write my own agent to solve this problem.

It's ridiculously easy to deploy and connects to statsd instead of directly to Influx DB.

https://github.com/eranbetzalel/statsd-agent-js/